# How to return null in hive udf in scala?

Tags: scala, hive, udf

I am working on a Hive UDF in Scala

```
class MyUDF extends UDF {
    def func(a: Double): Double {
        if (cond){ how to return null in this case? }
        else {some double}
    }
}
```

I tried `null.asInstanceOf[Double]` but this gives the output as 0. I need a NULL output in hive instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Scala `Double` cannot be `null`. Can you change the interface to return a `java.lang.Double`?